# Как автоматически вставить ссылку со страницы, написаной на php в код страницы html?

Tags: html, php

Как автоматически вставить ссылку со страницы, написаной на php в код страницы html?

Comment: Всмысле echo "<a></a>" ?

Comment: В смысле изначально ссылка берется из строки браузера и вставляется в php документ. Далее мне необходимо что бы эта ссылка автоматически встала в код странице <a></a>. Я создаю партнерский сайт так вот вся эта задумка состоит в том что бы с одного сайта множество партнеров могли бы продвигать свои партнерские ссылки.

Comment: Если честно, не понял, в чем суть. Отвечу на то, что понял. Можно на JavaScript делать. Через `innerHtml`, на каждой странице будет эта ссылка.

Comment: А можно поподробней, где его взять то javascript, как его написать?

Comment: В общем, так:

    <div id = 'sslika'>
    Ваша ссылка
    </div>

Вот на javascript для кайдои странице вставиш скрипт (`<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'sample.js'>`). Далее уже `document.getElementById('ssilka').innerHTML = 'tvoya ssilka';`,
Ну если ссылок много должно быть, то по-другому. Не знаю, помогло или нет.

Comment: @koko, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то присмотритесь к массиву **$_SERVER**.
Например для *example.com/some/script.php*:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // выведет example.com
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // выведет /some/script.php
```